# Using a latch vs an AND gate to reduce switching activity in a low power VLSI design

Tags: low-power, vlsi, interview-questions

Here is a problem that pops in low power design interview questions. The solution is the second picture down.

Why not use AND gates in place of the D-Latch? The person who created the solution did not go into this topic at all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a well documented topic. AND gates causes glitches in clock line, it can violate pulse width rule on clock as well. D latch is the classic solution to above two problems.

Comment: @MituRaj, the question is not about clock gating. The question is about data gating. Basically the data is being zeroed.

Answer (score 4):

Think about what would happen if half of the bits in the inputs were logic `1` most of the time. Using an AND gate would force those to become `0` when the other AND input is `0`, so these bits would toggle on every cycle of your circuit and you would actually **increase** the power consumption due to switching.

Using a latch instead means that the inputs to your circuit only switch states when they really need to for proper computation.